# CGAL - Given a line L and distance D in R^2, how to find equations of the lines parallel to L at distance D from L?

Tags: geometry, cgal

I have a line *L* in the Euclidean plane and a scalar *D*, and I want to find
the 2 lines that are parallel to *L* and is at a distance of *D* from *L*.
How can I do that in CGAL?
The api **CGAL::parallel** is for comparing if two lines/segments/rays are
parallel, not for returning a parallel line. The api **Line_2< Kernel >
perpendicular (const Point_2< Kernel > &p) const** can be used to get the
equation of a line *N* normal to the line *L*, but I can't seem to find a
way to get the point at a distance *D* from *L* on the normal *N*. (If I can
get such a point *P*, I can generate the line parallel to *L* passing
through *P* to get my desired line equation).

Thoughts? I'm sure there is a way using some other API's, but I can't seem
to find it (I've looked pretty thoroughly through 2D and 3D Linear Geometry
Kernel API list, and have checked the APIs whose names sound promising).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You [can get](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Kernel_23/classCGAL_1_1Line__2.html) a, b, c parameters of general line equation

```
a * x + b * y + c = 0
```

Then normalize it dividing by

```
d = Sqrt(a * a + b * b)
```

obtaining

```
A * x + B * y + C = 0, where
A = a / d 
B = b / d 
C = c / d
```

and make parallel lines equations with  parameters `(A, B, C + D)` and `(A, B, C - D)`  (where D is your distance)

If Line_2.direction is normalized, it would simpler to use another approach:

```
dir = L.direction
p = L.point
p1  = Point(p.x + dir.y * D, p.y - dir.x * D)
p2  = Point(p.x - dir.y * D, p.y + dir.x * D)
L1 = Line_2(p1, dir)
L2 = Line_2(p2, dir)
```